# iOS 6.0 / iPhone 5 detecting Bluetooth 4.0 dongle

Tags: iphone, core-bluetooth

Does CoreBluetooth allow detection of a Bluetooth 4.0 dongle? Or does the peripheral device have to be under the "Made for iPhone" program to be detected?

Answer (score 1):

The dongle essentially turns the Simulator from an iPhone 4 *(without BLE4.0 support)* to iPhone 4S *(with BLE4.0 support)*

If you are using an older Mac, then there are some things you need to do to make it load your dongle.

http://www.atpeaz.com/index.php/2012/using-unsupported-bluetooth-4-0-usb-dongle-with-os-x/

Then, you need to issue a Terminal command so the Simulator will use the new BLE 4.0 dongle.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2295/_index.html

### Terminal Command

This needs to be issued while the Simulator is NOT running, after this command, then launch the Simulator.

```
sudo nvram bluetoothHostControllerSwitchBehavior="never"
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the dongle the peripheral device that you want to talk to?

The dongle does not need to be MFI to be detected. If you are using iPhone 4S (with bluetooth 4.0), you can talk to it without it being MFI. However, if your device does not support bluetooth 4.0, talking to the device (ie, create EASession, NSStreamInput/Output) requires that device being MFI.

Comment: I plugged the Bluetooth 4.0 dongle (bought from ebay for $10) into my computer, but the iphone scan can't seem to find it from the Bluetooth menu. Is there some configuration I need to do in the computer side? I turned "Allow other devices to find" on.

Comment: What iPhone do you use? 4? 4s? Or 5 as you specified in the title

Comment: well, do you have other devices that support bluetooth 4 (iPad 3 or new macs)? Try to see if those devices can or cannot detect your dongle.